# Is it possible to query a specific index of a postgres array with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

With a database column migrated like this:

```
add_column :documents, :array_column, :string, array: true
```

I understand it's possible to do this to query any element of the array:

```
Document.where("'foo' = ANY (array_column)")
```

My question is whether or not I can specifically query the second (or any other single) element of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the usual array indexing notation but remember that SQL arrays are 1-based rather than 0-based:

```
Document.where("array_column[2] = 'foo'")
```

The fine manual has more on [accessing arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING).